# React : How to render a component which depends on the data rendered by other components

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I have three components 'FirstName', 'LastName' and 'FullName'. 'FirstName' and 'LastName' components are independent and makes seperate server calls to fetch the data(Using Flux Architecture). Now I have a page which uses all the components and I want to render the 'FullName' component by using data fetched by other two.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Flux architecture, then your components shouldn't be responsible for fetching the data themselves. That should happen within the appropriate store. However, the components *can* dispatch an action which triggers the fetching of the data at the store.

It makes a lot more sense to derive a child relationship from the `Fullname` component to the `FirstName` and `LastName` components, rather than trying to go the other way—trying to derive a parent from its logical children.

```
function FirstName(props) {
  return <span>{props.firstName}</span>;
}

function LastName(props) {
  return <span>{props.lastName}</span>;
}

function FullName(props) {
  return (
    <span>
      <FirstName name={props.name} />
      <LastName name={props.name} />
    </span>
  );
}
```

If you need to render one of the children by themselves, you can reach into the appropriate store for the name object, then pass it as a prop and let the component render the correct part.

```
let name = UserStore.getName(id);

// to render full name
return <FullName name={name} />

// to render first name
return <FirstName name={name} />

// to render last name
return <LastName name={name} />
```

If you have a very good reason for fetching the data within your components, then you make `FullName` a wrapper component which passes an `id` down to the `FirstName` and `LastName` components so that they can fetch their data individually.

```
function FullName(props) {
  return (
    <span>
      <FirstName id={props.id} />
      <LastName id={props.id} />
    </span>
  );
}
```

But be aware that by letting components manage substates of your application goes directly against the Flux architecture. All meaningful change should be triggered by actions, so that it can be replayed, debugged and logged.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Dan Prince
But still may be you need 3 separate components which are not directly related as per your requirement. You can go with following image(assuming you have knowledge of how flux works) [flux solution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkq5H.jpg)